# Comparing booleans from two sets of observations and counting TRUE matches in R

Tags: r, boolean, comparison, na

I have a two data sets of only booleans (and NAs). I'm trying to run a while loops that will iterate between each observation (each data set has 227496 observations) and count whenever both are TRUE. My code is this:

```
while(i<=227496){
  if(upperX[i] == TRUE & upperY[i] == TRUE){
    count = count+1
  }
  i = i+1
}
```

It goes up to i = 195 before returning the error:

```
Error in if (upperX[i] == TRUE & upperY[i] == TRUE) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

At upperX[195] and upperY[195] both are NA, which I'm assuming is why this is happening, but any time I try to create an exception for this instance I'm getting:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
```

Comment: You can change your code to look for values that are TRUE and non-missing. Try changing the relevant line to `if((!is.na(upperX[i]) & upperX[i]) & (!is.na(upperY[i]) & upperY[i])) `. That said, this should be done using vectors ... `sum(upperX & upperY, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: I posted my answer before I saw this, yours is cleaner.

Comment: ty, feel free to incorporate my comment into your answer, if you wish [as a side note, I tend to use for loops in cases like this, which means you dont need to define i outside the loop or update it within)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add an exception to the event that one of the values were NA, since NA does not show up as FALSE when asked if it's TRUE, it just shows up as NA.

My solution:

```
while(i<=227496){
  if(is.na(upperX[i]) | is.na(upperY[i])){
    count = count
  }
  else if(upperX[i] == TRUE & upperY[i] == TRUE){
    count = count+1
  }
  i = i+1
}
```

This first checks if either are NA, and keeps the count constant if one is. Otherwise it goes on to check if both are true, and keeps the count constant if they are.